# Use kartik-v php-date-formatter with Node Package Manager npm

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, npm, kartik-v

https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-date-formatter

How can I use this plugin using npm with Laravel 5.3

After successful installation. I used

```
const phpDateFormatter = require('php-date-formatter');
console.log(phpDateFormatter);
```

But phpDateFormatter do not come with any plugin data.
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks :)